# Task manager on windows 6.0 ce for Motorola MC3190 Handheld Computer

Tags: windows, windows-ce, taskmanager

I try to find out why a web page causes a memory leak on Motorola MC3190.

Barcode scanners are new with Windows 6.0 CE. There are no programs installed only default. We use it only IE.

When we used it for two weeks on, scanner memory ran out and it crashed. After the full restart, it works normally, restarting only Internet Explorer doesn't help.
Only Internet Explorer is being used.
I try to find some program like task manager to find out if IE has a memory leak.

I ask because Windows CE 6.0 doesn't have a task manager.

Any ideas on how to check the memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

I question whether you did much investigation on your own.  A simple search engine query for me turned up a lot of promising results like these:

- [Task Manager on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30871/Task-Manager-for-Windows-Mobile-and-Windows-CE)
- [iTaskManager](http://urana.info/mobile/wince/itaskmgr/index.html)
- [Remote Task Monitor](http://www.remotetaskmonitor.com/)
- [Windows CE Task Manager](http://www.vttoth.com/CMS/index.php/222)

In addition, if all you want to do is monitor a process' memory usage, rolling your own monitoring app using [the toolhelp APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450774.aspx) would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for answer, the last one work`s great. I find out explore.exe is rising 10 MB per day.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the remote task monitor for wince. It does the job well. https://www.osletek.com/pg/2186/Remote_Task_Monitor_for_Embedded_Devices